QCNCM865 causes laptop fans to stay active in sleep/standby
I replaced my wifi card from a Mediatek MT7925 to a Qualcomm QCNCM865. The Qualcomm card works great, except that it causes the fans to run while the computer is in sleep/standby mode. I switched back to the mediatek card and it can sleep with the fans off like normal again.
I ran the Windows SleepStudy utility and found that while sleeping with the Qualcomm card installed, the "PCI Express Root Port (_SB.PCI0.GPP5)" is active 99% of the time. When I expand that tab, I see the component is "Qualcomm FastConnect 7800 Wi-Fi 7 High Band Simultaneous (HBS) Network Adapter (_SB.PCI0.GPP5.WLAN)". So I know the Qualcomm network card is causing the problem. I tried uninstalling the driver and removed the device in device manager, but even then the fans still blow when it's supposed to be sleeping. It seems just physically having the card installed causes the problem.
screenshot from sleep study report
My laptop is the new ROG Zephyrus g16 ga605 with AMD Ryzen AI 9 HX 370.
Does anyone have ideas for how to diagnose this?
